# Return directives used by dateutil.parser

Tags: python, python-dateutil

Is there a way to get back the directives that dateutil used to parse a date?

```
from dateutil import parser

dstr = '2017/10/01 16:44'
dtime = parser.parse(dstr)
```

What I would like is the ability to get `'%Y/%m/%d %H:%M'` back somehow.

Comment: What is your use case for this? Do you have certain formats that you consider valid, and others that you consider invalid?

Comment: @chrisz matching a small group of date strings in one format to a much much larger group of date strings in a different format. It seems more efficient to detect the format of the larger group, and convert the smaller group to that format than to parse both groups into datetime objects

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the parser in `dateutil` has no support for extracting a format. The parser uses a mix of tokenizing and heuristics to try to figure out what the various numbers and words in the input could mean, and no 'format' is build up during this process.

Your best bet is to search the input string for the fields from the resulting datetime object and produce a format from *that*.

For your specific example, that is a reasonable option, because all the resulting values are unique. If your inputs do not have unique values, you'll have include heuristics where you use multiple examples to increase the certainty of a correct match.

For example, for your specific example, you can find unique positions for all the datetime components presented as strings, starting with `'2017'`, `'10'`, etc. However, for other examples you'll have to search for different variants of string representations of those components, like a 2-year format, or month, day, hour or minute components not using zero-padding, and you need to account for a 12-hour clock representation.

I haven't directly tried this, but I strongly suspect that this is a problem very suitable for the [*Aho–Corasick algorithm*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_algorithm), which lets you find positions of matching known strings (the dictionary, here your various datetime components formatted as strings, plus potential delimiter characters) in an input string. Once you have those positions, and you have resolved the ambiguities, you can construct a format string from those. You can probably narrow down the number of possible component formats by looking for tell-tale strings like `pm` or weekdays or month names.

There are ready-made Python implementations, like the [`pyahocorasick` package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyahocorasick). With that library I was able to make a pretty good approximation in a few steps:

```
>>> from dateutil import parser
>>> import ahocorasick
>>> A = ahocorasick.Automaton()
>>> dstr = '2017/10/01 16:44'
>>> dtime = parser.parse(dstr)
>>> formats = 'dmyYHIpMS'
>>> for f in formats:
...     _ = A.add_word(dtime.strftime(f'%{f}'), (False, f))
...
>>> for p in ':/ ':
...     _ = A.add_word(p, (True, p))
...
>>> A.make_automaton()
>>> for end_index, (punctuation, char) in A.iter(dstr):
...     print(end_index, char if punctuation else f'%{char}')
...
2 %d
3 %Y
3 %y
4 /
6 %m
7 /
9 %d
10
12 %H
13 :
15 %M
```

You could include priorities, and only output a specific formatter when punctuation is reached; that'll resolve the `%d / %Y / %y` clash at the start.

Comment: "search the input string for the fields from the resulting datetime object and produce a format from that" 

- but what about a subtle difference like `dstr = '2017/10/01 1644'`

Comment: @Sebastian: The components present in that string are still unique. `datetime(2017, 10, 1, 16, 44, 0)` as a result, you can still find the strings `'2017'`, `'10'`, `'01'`, `'16'` and `'44'`, each in unique positions. You do need to try to find `'17'` (2-digit year), and `'1'` (single-digit day of the month) and `'04'` and `'4'` for a 12-hour clock (with a possibility for the presence of `'pm'`).

Comment: Yes but you wouldn't be able to tell the difference between the input string having a `":"` or not. The crux of my question

Comment: @Sebastian: why not? You have the input string and the components. Once you located the various datetime parts, you can find those delimiters too.

Comment: I suppose. I could see this getting much more complex that my little brain can handle for less optimal date strings. e.g. `3/9/18 3:13pm`.

Comment: @Sebastian: yup, that's an example of a more difficult value to parse, because the `3`s are not unique. At that point you use heuristics, as the year and `9` are matched to one area, and the `13` for the minutes to another. That makes it much more likely that the second `3` is the hour, in 12-hour clock format.